# What's the difference in these two definitions of little-o (from CLRS vs. Wiley algorithms books)?

Tags: asymptotics

*Algorithm Design: Foundations, Analysis, and Internet Examples* by Goodrich and Tamassia (Wiley, 2002) defines little-o as follows:

$o(g(n)) = \{ f(n) : \forall c > 0,\ \exists n_0 > 0\ \text{such that } \forall n \geq n_0,\  0 \leq f(n) \leq cg(n) \}$.

This definition differs slightly by strictness in the last inequality from that of *Introduction to Algorithms* by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald Rivest,  and Clifford Stein  (MIT, 2009) which defines as:

$o(g(n)) = \{ f(n) : \forall c > 0,\ \exists n_0 > 0\ \text{such that } \forall n \geq n_0,\  0 \leq f(n) < cg(n) \}$.

The latter definition is what I primarily see in other sources, too. Are these equivalent due to the choice of any constant c? If not, which is standard? (I assume it is the CLRS one.)

Comment: The CLRS has $o(0)=\emptyset$, for one thing, whereas GT has $o(0)=\{\text{sequences that are eventually }0\}$.

Comment: Also, CRLS has $o(g)=\emptyset$ for all $g$ which are frequently $0$.

Comment: Personally, I like better $o(g)=\{f\,:\, \forall c>0,\exists m,\ \forall n>m,\ \lvert f(n)\rvert\le c\lvert g(n)\rvert\}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Do you mean to write $n \geq n_0$ in both definitions?

Comment: @kccu Yes, I corrected above.

Comment: @Gae.S.   Thanks, those are good examples. Is this difference common among varying little-o definitions or is GT an outlier?

Comment: @Agrajag I don't know. My opinion is that CRLS might have had the one by GT in mind and that they overlooked the pathologies of the more general situation because they were concerned just with strictly increasing functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one is standard. $$o(g)=\{f: \forall c>0\,\exists n_0\,\forall n>n_0\,(|f(n)|\le c|g(n)|)\}.$$

Comment: It is also common to write that a function is $equal$ to $o(g)$ which  means that it belongs to the $set$ $o(g)$. E.g.  $n^2+3n=n^2(1+o(1)).$